# Trino REST API documentation

Tags: presto, trino

I'm developing a Trino solution and I'm looking for the REST API documentation.
I already looked on their official documentation [here](https://trino.io/docs/current/develop/client-protocol.html) but there are a lot of endpoints that are not listed on this page (Like /v1/status or /v1/query).
Is there any full documentation of the REST API available?

Thank you,
Yair